# SQL Filter Time range with Time zone converted values

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to filter a database within time range. I wrote something like this below.

```
WHERE
    CAST(DateTimeColumn AS TIME) BETWEEN CAST(@StartTime AS TIME) 
                                     AND CAST(@EndTime AS TIME)
```

This works as it should, but the problem occurs when the parameters are converted from Time zone change. For example, I've set the default time as 12:00am to 11:59pm to cover 23:59 hours of range. When these parameters are changed to UTC time from Singapore time zone, it becomes 04:00pm to 03:59pm. Thus, covering -1 minute of time range or in code it becomes.

```
WHERE 
     CAST(DateTimeColumn AS TIME) BETWEEN 04:00pm AND 03:59pm
```

The code above will not return anything since it searched negative timeframe.

I have searched and learned that I can use `NOT BETWEEN` and `CASE` to accommodate all different Time zones. Is there an easier way to make this work without writing CASE statement for every possible time zones?

Comment: Surely you must be storing the date as well? So just make it a datetime comparison. Sample data and desired results would help clarify your question.

Comment: @DaleK This condition in the where clause is only looking for time aspect only. I'll try to add examples.

Comment: You shouldn't need to cast your parameters to time if you define them as time in the first place?

Comment: And are you happy that you fully understand the way `BETWEEN` operates? Because its inclusive of start and finish it can be a bit unintuitive.

Comment: @DaleK Right, but these parameters are coming from C# and it was passed as DateTime type, so I had to cast it to get rid of the dates. And, I didn't know that it was inclusive and that works out for me.

Comment: So change your C# to pass a time datatype - you should use the correct datatypes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

1. if `@StartTime` is less then `@EndTime` then check if your column time is between the `@StartTime` and `@EndTime`
2. if `@StartTime` is greater then `@EndTime` then check if your column time is greater than your `@StartTime` or less than your `@EndTime`.

```
(@StartTime < @EndTime AND CAST(DateTimeColumn AS TIME) BETWEEN @StartTime AND @EndTime)
OR (@StartTime > @EndTime AND (CAST(DateTimeColumn AS TIME) >= @StartTime OR CAST(DateTimeColumn AS TIME) <= @EndTime))
```

Comment: I didn't know writing the condition like this translated to if statements. I am going to try and see if it works.

Comment: Its straight forward AND/OR logic :) should be fundamental to any software/SQL training.

Comment: SQL is hard for me :(

Comment: @NewClind no worries. And for future reference, do make sure you add sample data and desired results to your question - it makes it much easier to understand what you are looking for.